# Why does iMacros only support javascript files on Palemoon or lower version of FireFox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

The title explains my question. for context: I made a javascript file for iMacros but it *only* works for Palemoon and lower versions of Firefox. Is there any possible way to get around this without downgrading Firefox? I don't want to use Palemoon all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already answered your Qt many times on the iMacros Forum, [here](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=31025#p85438) and [here](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=31196#p86089) for example to only mention 2 recent Threads from the last few months from a quick Check...

And otherwise, convert your '.js' Script (back) to pure '.iim'... You can do "everything" in pure '.iim', I've never used a '.js' Script myself, while being an "Advanced" User...
And '.iim' Scripts will work in all Versions of iMacros and all 4 Browsers supported by iMacros, without relying on '.js' Script Support...

Comment: Alright..., Thanks for accepting my Answer... My Answer actually contains 5 different Options, 2 of which you've already mentioned yourself... Maybe interesting for other Users would be if you could mention which one you chose... And I would be able to help if you chose for the "(Re)converting (back) to pure '.iim'" one, if you need any Help... (But rather on the iMacros Forum, this is not "really" an "easy" Qt + "direct" Answer for this Forum...)